# Making an image move arrond the screen with key presses

Tags: python, pygame

I had this script working before but now it doesnt work. Earlier, the image moved around the screen fine but now it wont even move, the image just stays in the corner not moving at all when i press up or down or left or right keys

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

bifl = 'screeing.jpg'
milf = 'char_fowed_walk1.png'

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
background = pygame.image.load(bifl).convert()
mouse_c = pygame.image.load(milf).convert_alpha()


x, y = 0, 0
movex, movey = 0, 0

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                movex =- 0.3
            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                movex =+ 0.3
            elif event.key == K_UP:
                movey =- 0.3
            elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                movey =+ 0.3

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                movex = 0
            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                movex = 0
            elif event.key == K_UP:
                movey = 0
            elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                movey = 0



    x += movex
    y += movey

    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(mouse_c, (x, y))

    pygame.display.update()
```

I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is change the second `KEYDOWN` to `KEYUP` so that your movement speed doesn't get set to 0 whenever you press a key.

EDIT: Additionally you have some strange syntax in your code. `=-` and `=+` are not Python operators. I think you meant `+=` and `-=`. Also remember to use `elif` statements instead of `if` statements whenever possible. Not only does this optimize your code, it also makes it easier to understand and debug.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

bifl = 'screeing.jpg'
milf = 'char_fowed_walk1.png'

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
background = pygame.image.load(bifl).convert()
mouse_c = pygame.image.load(milf).convert_alpha()


x, y = 0, 0
movex, movey = 0, 0

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                movex -= 0.3
            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                movex += 0.3
            elif event.key == K_UP:
                movey -= 0.3
            elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                movey += 0.3

        elif event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                movex = 0
            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                movex = 0
            elif event.key == K_UP:
                movey = 0
            elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                movey = 0



    x += movex
    y += movey

    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(mouse_c, (x, y))

    pygame.display.update()
```